# SSH login problem under 12.04 server edition

Tags: server, ssh, login

I've got problem with ssh login after fresh installment of 12.04 server edition.

Every time it promotes: `Authentication Fail`, and I am pretty sure my password is OK.

I actually tried several ssh clients and several user names, all fail.

There is no log from `/var/log/auth.log`

And I've enabled PasswordAuthentication in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Any hint would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log), also use `ssh -vvv` on the client side to better see what's going on.

Comment: Don't know whether I read this correctly... I've tried to add -d option on cmd line of sshd, but still get no log.

Comment: And I've run client on win7, so don't know any easy way to run ssh -vvv... Another strange thing is when I ssh from the same host (using either localhost or external ip), login did work.

Comment: You can get a commandline ssh [here](http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-command-line-ssh/). Also, could it be a firewall problem?

Comment: @MadMike It should not be a firewall issue since I can get the promote for password. But thanks very much for the ssh tool link, just seems quite slow to open the page, will download and try later

Answer (score 0):

SSH by default is logging failed connection attempts to `/var/log/auth.log`. 
Since you just installed the system, nobody disabled it, and you cannot login.

**Conclusion**: You are getting connected somewhere else (on your router/firewall).

I would guess you are trying to connect over the internet (say from home to work) but you are stumbling on some network gear which also has SSH running.

You could add some more information in your post for better troubleshooting.